# how to add multiple unlisted items to a class?

Tags: python, list, class

This may be a very simple question and has probably been asked before, but it's probably an issue of me [lacking vocabulary](http://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/2w3byo/self_taught_professionals_what_were_your_areas_of/conabi0), so I apologize in advance.

From [the python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html):

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.tricks = []    # creates a new empty list for each dog
    def add_trick(self, trick):
        self.tricks.append(trick)

d = Dog('Fido')
d.add_trick('roll over')
d.add_trick('fetch')
d.tricks
```

This returns, as expected:

```
['roll over', 'fetch']
```

But if I then run:

```
d.add_trick('play dead', 'high five')
```

I get an error, so I tried:

```
d.add_trick(['play dead', 'high five'])
```

But that gives me:

```
d.tricks
['roll over', 'fetch', ['play dead', 'high five']]
```

When I want:

```
['roll over', 'fetch', 'play dead', 'high five']
```

How can I unlist a list of items added to a class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `extend`:

```
d.tricks.extend(['play dead', 'high five'])

d.tricks
['roll over', 'fetch', 'play dead', 'high five']
```

Or you could change `add_tricks` to:

```
def add_trick(self, *trick):
    self.tricks.extend(trick)
```

Comment: I like this answer because it's only one extra thing! And now I've learned `extend`! I'll mark it as answered as soon as it will let me (there's apparently a time limit?)

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine the `Dog.add_trick` method to take a variable number of arguments and then add them all to the list using [`list.extend`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

```
def add_trick(self, *tricks):
    self.tricks.extend(tricks)
```

Demo:

```
>>> class Dog:
...     def __init__(self, name):
...         self.name = name
...         self.tricks = []
...     def add_trick(self, *tricks):
...         self.tricks.extend(tricks)
...
>>> d = Dog('Fido')
>>> d.add_trick('roll over')
>>> d.add_trick('fetch')
>>> d.tricks
['roll over', 'fetch']
>>> d.add_trick('play dead', 'high five')
>>> d.tricks
['roll over', 'fetch', 'play dead', 'high five']
>>>
```

More on the `*tricks` syntax can be found under [Function definitions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) in the documentation.